# Send Array from HTML table to Php Array with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an HTML table and I get the values from that table with JavaScript.

I put them in arrays, but I'm having troubles when I send them to PHP using AJAX.

Here is my JavaScript, because it doesn't call my PHP file. Actually it doesn't do anything:

JavaScript:

```
function getData(tableID) {
  var qty = [];
  var messureUnit = [];
  var price = [];
  var total = [];
  var table = x(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
    messureUnit[i] = table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;
    price[i] = table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML;
    price[i] = table.rows[i].cells[4].innerHTML;
    qty[i] = table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
  }
  var array = JSON.stringify(qty);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: { array1: array },
    url: "DataReceiver.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
      $('#resp').val(response);
    }
  });
}
```

PHP:

```
$qty=json_decode($_POST['array1']);
if($_POST['array1'])
{
    $message="received";     
}
echo json_encode($message);
```

HTML:

I call the JavaScript with a button:

```
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="recogerDatosD('tblFactD');"></button>
<input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="resp" name="resp">
```

Comment: Did you debug your code from the dev tool ?

Comment: So it's not accessing DataReceiver.php? Have you correctly named that file? And is it located in the same folder as the file with the javascript code?

To be more explicit, you could change url: "DataReceiver.php" to url: "/ajax/DataReceiver.php" or wherever the file is located relative to the root.

Comment: @MatthewLymer  yes, i've the file in the same folder as the javascript code, and it's correctly named

Comment: Ok. Are you sure it's having trouble reading the PHP file? It could just be that the code in your PHP file is incorrect. I would recommend trying $_REQUEST instead of $_POST in the PHP file.

Comment: @MatthewLymer yeah, i've the php debug and it doesn't get in anytime

Comment: `$_POST['array']` should be `$_POST['array1']` as that is the key in the data object - `data: {array1 : array}`

Comment: Sorry I meant $_REQUEST not $_RESPONSE (edited)

Comment: @ImClarky is correct! Also if $_POST fails, try $_REQUEST - as I've had to do that before (even with a POST ajax).

Comment: @ImClarky yeah, sorry, i have it like you said in my code

Comment: @MatthewLymer so i use POST on the ajax but $_REQUEST in the php?

Comment: Sounds odd I know, but I've had to do that in the past to get it to work! Also, if that fails, I normally just use a direct POST ajax, which has this format:

$.post("DataReceiver.php", { array1: array }, function(response) { ...

Comment: edited for readability and grammar.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere that `getData()`, your javascript function, is getting called.

Your `onclick` method on the button is referencing another function that we do not see defined anywhere: `onclick="recogerDatosD('tblFactD');"`

Instead, that should be

```
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="getData('tblFactD');"></button>
```

Also make sure that `'tblFactD'` is the ID set on the table that you are trying to serialize and POST.